# Multiple URLs same destination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, naming

Is it bad practice to have multiple URLs leading to the same destination?

Rest assured, that these URLs are unique. For example:

page.com/model/hello-there == page.com/model/hellothere == page.com/model/h-e-lloth-ere

All are reduced down to the letters (/hellothere).

Are there any disadvantages to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're alluding to is known as [`slugging`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL)

I'd highly recommended checking out that link, and some gems including [Slugalicious](https://github.com/RISCfuture/slugalicious) & [Friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

There is absolutely no problem with it, as long as you structure the routes properly. For example, as a user, I'd welcome `/users/mark-zuckerberg` rather than `users/109234230234/mark-zuckerberg/z22323` (it's all about user experience at the end of the day)